# Lifetime error while transferring custom token to dynamic list of accounts

Tags: anchor, spl-token, anchor-spl

I have a dynamic list of accounts which I need to transfer spl tokens to, I am using the following function:

```
  pub fn transfer_token(ctx: Context<TransferToken>, amount_of_tokens:u64) -> Result<()> {
         let vec: Vec<AccountInfo> = ctx.remaining_accounts.to_vec();

          for elem in vec.iter(){

            let transfer_instruction = Transfer{
            from: ctx.accounts.from.to_account_info(),
            to: elem.to_account_info().to_account_info(),
            authority: ctx.accounts.from_authority.to_account_info(),
        };
         
        let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info();
        // Create the Context for our Transfer request
        let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(cpi_program, transfer_instruction);

        // Execute anchor's helper function to transfer tokens
        anchor_spl::token::transfer(cpi_ctx, amount_of_tokens)?;
        // iterate by-value
    }
        Ok(())
    }
```

However, when I build, I get the following error:

```
 pub fn transfer_token(ctx: Context<TransferToken>, amount_of_tokens:u64) -> Result<()> {
    |                                ----------------------
    |                                        |
    |                                        these two types are declared with different lifetimes...
130 |          let vec: Vec<AccountInfo> = ctx.remaining_accounts.to_vec();
    |                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ...but data from `ctx` flows into `ctx` here
```

I recon this has something to do with the lifetime of transfer instruction but I cannot figure out how to fix this.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and explicitly align the function and arguments lifetimes.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html

```
pub fn transfer_token<'a>(
 ctx: Context<TransferToken<'a>,
 amount_of_tokens:u64) -> Result<()>
```